# Scrolling an image wider than screen

Tags: android, image, scroll, imageview, scrollview

I am trying to create a sort of progress bar for my Android app, however, I would like it to be an image moving from right to left. The image itself needs to preserve its original size.

Basically, what I am looking for is this (don't have enough rep to post image):

http://postimg.org/image/5e7w5vd7h/

The problem is that the image, which is 2000px wide, will not load when run on my device (Sony Xperia S). If I use an image with width <= device width, it works.

I have tried using HorizontalScrollView and ScrollView inside a RelativeLayout, as well as setting scaleType to center, centerCrop, fitXY and all the others, adjustViewBounds true/false etc., basically every combination there is.

First and foremost, I would just like the image to appear on my device - the animation in itself is not prioritized right now, but I am thinking of a solution where I increment the ImageView's paddingRight regularly.

Below is a snippet of my XML thus far:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12.5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/rolling_bar"
            android:scaleType="center" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countdown_time_text"
        android:text="01:22:58"
        android:textColor="@color/countdown_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

I apologize for any syntactical / semantic errors, I am quite new to Android. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "will not load", what exactly happens? You get an exception, or just the image isn't showing?

Comment: Seems like the image is simply TOO big, it's causing an OOM exception or something, you need to do something similar to Google maps whereby they load the image as smaller tiles and only display the part of the image it needs, saving memory, there is librarys around for this.

Comment: i agree with @xBroak, 1 way of fixing this is using a webview.

Comment: You can't load that much data into memory. You need to cap the image height to the height of the screen, and adjust the width proportionately.